# How to get updated columns from a table?

Tags: sql-server

I am working with SQL Server Triggers. And I need a sql query to find columns from a table whose values has been updated using of INSERTED and DELETED tables.

Can anyone help me out on this ? For ex -

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(MAX), LName nvarchar(max), Address1 Nvarchar(max),id int)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(MAX), LName nvarchar(max), Address1 Nvarchar(max), id int)


insert into @T1 values('Ricky','Broad','a b road',1)

insert into @T1 values('Mike','Halls','m g road',2)


insert into @T2 values('Ricky_Update','Broad','a b road',1)

insert into @T2 values('Mike','Halls','m g road',2)


;WITH ChangedData AS (
SELECT d.name , d.LName FROM @T1 d
EXCEPT 
SELECT i.name , i.LName  FROM @T2 i
)
```

I tried to find out by "EXCEPT" but it's returning whole updated row. And I need only updated columns like in above example I only need-

Name column for id =1 because it's updated.

Comment: Can you post some example of what you have tried before?

Comment: For what purpose? You will use this tables AFTER insertion/deletion complete or INSTEAD?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do except for individual columns and then do Union.

```
    SELECT NAME
FROM (
    SELECT d.NAME
    FROM @T1 d
    WHERE id = 1

    EXCEPT

    SELECT i.NAME
    FROM @T2 i
    WHERE id = 1
    ) A

UNION

SELECT LName
FROM (
    SELECT d.LName
    FROM @T1 d
    WHERE id = 1

    EXCEPT

    SELECT i.LName
    FROM @T2 i
    WHERE id = 1
    ) B
```

Comment: thanks. Yes we can achieve it by above code. But in case of large number of columns like 100,120 etc, we have to write more statements. So is there any other way to find it.